# auto-resize columns of a grid with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I have a grid. I have four columns. The width of each column is 25%. I would like it if one of the column widths exceeds 25%. Column width to be 50%. If the width of one of the columns is more than 50%, the columns become 100%. please help me, thanks

- **note:**

  1. each column => text-overflow    (4-col => 2-col)
  2. Page size is fixed (no responsive). For example, if the font size is enlarged or the text is enlarged, the 4-col grid will be converted to a 2-col grid (50%)
  3. The height is fixed and single-line.

[image]

if text width < 25% => 4-col

```
<h2>text length: short  => 4column </h2>
  <ul class="grid cards">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

if text width >= 25% => 2-col

```
<h2>text length: medium  => 2column </h2>

  <ul class="grid cards">
    <li>item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1item 1 item 1 item 1item 1item 1item s1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

if text width >= 50% => 1-col

```
 <h2>text length: large  => 1column </h2>
  <ul class="grid cards">
    <li>item 1 item 1 item 1 item 1item 1 item 1 item 1item 1item 1item sitem 1 item 1item 1item 1item sitem 1 item 1 item 1 item 1item 1 item 1 item 1item 1item 1item  1 item 1 item 1 item 1item 1 item 1 item 1item 1item 1item s11</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Look into flexbox or CSS grid.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this demo to solve this by CSS Grid, without using media queries. `link` https://codepen.io/tripti1410/live/Zmoaxr